# ¿Por qué el addEventListener se ejecuta más de una vez?

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo un código del cual espero que al darle click al clicame muestre H y que al darle click al h se añada un hijo a clicame. El  problema viene cuando hago más de un click sobre clicame, esperaba que solo se le añadiese un hijo al clicame, pero al ejecutarlo pasa otra cosa diferente:

```js
document.querySelector('.no').addEventListener('click', añadir);
function añadir(e) {
  const x = document.querySelector('.h').style;
  const no = e.target;
  x.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('.h').addEventListener('click', function () {añadirElemento(no);});
  function añadirElemento(no) {
    const sq = document.createElement('p');
    no.appendChild(sq);
    sq.textContent = 'Text';
  }
}
```

```css
.h{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="no">Clicame</div>
<div class='h'>H</div>
```

Lo que pasa esque no entiendo porqué al clicar sobre clicame se ejecuta lo de dentro de de la funcion añadirElemento tantas veces como he pulsado en clicame. Pienso que es porqué se le ha añadido más de una vez el addEventListener al elemento y por eso. Pero no estoy seguro. ¿Porqué pasa esto?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas en el código, cada vez que haces `click` en `.no`, además de mostrar `.h` también esta agregando un `listener` a elemento.

Por poner un ejemplo: si haces `click` 5 veces en `.no`, entonces cuando hagas `click` en `.h` se van a crear 5 `<p>`.

#### Solución:

Mover el código que agrega el `listener` a '.h' fuera de la función `añadir`.

Ejemplo:

```js
document.querySelector(".no").addEventListener("click", añadir);
document.querySelector(".h").addEventListener("click", añadirElemento);

let no;

function añadir(e) {
  const x = document.querySelector(".h").style;
  no = e.target;
  x.display = "block";
}

function añadirElemento() {
  const sq = document.createElement("p");
  no.appendChild(sq);
  sq.textContent = "Text";
}
```

```css
.h {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="no">Clicame</div>
<div class='h'>H</div>
```

Comment: Entonces según tu ejemplo si yo hago 5 clicks en .no agrega cinco veces el addEventListener a .h y por eso se crean 5 p nuevos?

Comment: @Roberto, exactamente

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que tu código indica que la letra H (`.h`) tiene un `listener` a cada elemento, puedes remover el `listener` después de dar clic:

```js
    document.querySelector('.no').addEventListener('click', añadir);
    function añadir(e) {
      const x = document.querySelector('.h').style;
      const no = e.target;
      x.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('.h').addEventListener('click', function () {añadirElemento(no);});
      function añadirElemento(no) {
        const sq = document.createElement('p');
        no.appendChild(sq);
        sq.textContent = 'Text';
        //Remueve listener.
        document.querySelector('.h').removeEventListener('click', function () {añadirElemento(no);});
      }
    }
```

```css
.h{
       display: none;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="no">Clicame</div>
    <div class='h'>H</div>
```

Comment: Para poder remover un listener necesitas indicar la función por su nombre. Ejemplo: `el.addEventListener('click', nombreFn);` entonces podes hacer `el.removeEventListener('click', nombreFn);`

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que cada vez que haces clic en el elemento `.no` estás agregando un nuevo `listener`, de la cual el elemento `.h` se agregará las veces que el `listener` se repita.

Una solución sería separar los `listener` y las funciones, quedando así:

```js
document.querySelector('.no').addEventListener('click', agregar);
document.querySelector('.h').addEventListener('click', agregarElemento);

function agregar() {
  const x = document.querySelector('.h').style;
  x.display = 'block';
}

function agregarElemento(e) {
  const no = e.target;
  const sq = document.createElement('p');
  no.appendChild(sq);
  sq.textContent = 'Text';
}
```

```css
.h {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="no">Clicame</div>
<div class='h'>H</div>
```